# Python: saving numpy array to ROOT file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, root-framework

So my research mates and I are trying to save a pretty big (47104,5) array into a TTree in a ROOT file. The array on the Python side works fine. We can access everything and run normal commands, but when we run the root_numpy.array2root() command, we get a weird error.

> Object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

The code we are running for this portion is as follows:

```
import root_numpy as rnp
import numpy as np
import scipy
import logging

def save_array(outputArray, outputName):
    outputString =str(outputName)
    logging.info("Creating .Root file")
    rnp.array2root(outputArray,outputString,treename="Training_Variables",mode="recreate")
```

We placed the outputString variable as a way to make sure we were putting the filename in as a string. ( In our python terminal, we add .root at the end of outputName to save it as a .root file.).

Here is a picture of the terminal.
[Showing exact error location in root_numpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJW8d.jpg)

Pretty much, we are confused about why array2root() is calling for the len() of an object, which we dont think should have a len? It should just have a shape. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember to take good care to be sure that you have proper punctuation and grammar. It can be very distracting to see a sentence start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: My bad. I will change that immediately. Thank you!

Comment: you can use hdf5, at least I think you can.

Comment: What is HDF5? But @Pierre helped me out by telling me to make a structured array!

Comment: @zhilothebest you can use google to learn about hdf5. Specifically, h5py is probably the best solution for your problem _unless_ you're collaborating with someone who needs to use ROOT. Why do you need to use ROOT?

Comment: @Shep We are using ROOT, because the information we get from CERN will come in .root format. Specifically, their MVA program works more quickly in .root formats, then in other file sources. Other programs we have created for our analysis also are working with .root files, so we might as well be consistent.

Comment: Oh wow, someone outside CERN is using TMVA? And meanwhile here at CERN everyone is moving over to sklearn!

Comment: @Shep, My research professor is with CERN haha! What is sklearn? Because we are looking into using Neural Networks. What is CERN telling everyone to use for that?

Comment: CERN is a big and loose organization with a lot of differing opinions, so it's hard to say what "they" are recommending (we're in physics, not software!) TMVA offers a decent BTD implementation, but the NNs are pretty out of date. For a modern NN implementation, look at Theano or Keras (both are python-based).  [Scikit Learn (or sklearn)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) is slowly catching on here because: (1) it also implements as many algorithms as TMVA while being more user friendly and (2) it's better supported than TMVA. Note that in the interest of scope sklearn doesn't include deep NNs.

Comment: Sklearn doesnt do deep NN's? Interesting, because our research group was looking into moving into sklearn. But we might look into one of those others you recommended!

Comment: You _can_ do NNs with sklearn, but if focuses more on simpler, less rapidly evolving techniques. Anyway this is getting a bit chatty for stack overflow, but if you're interested in the machine learning activities around CERN I'd take a look at some of the presentations around http://iml.cern.ch/tiki-index.php?page=Indico. You should also be able to find the CERN-wide mailing list there. The short story is that TMVA is still pretty popular for historical reasons, but it's future is limited and there are already many better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion routines from NumPy arrays to ROOT datatypes work with structured arrays. See the two following links. (Not tested, but this is very likely the problem as the routines use the `arr.dtypes.names` and `arr.dtypes.fields` attributes).

http://rootpy.github.io/root_numpy/reference/generated/root_numpy.array2tree.html#root_numpy.array2tree

http://rootpy.github.io/root_numpy/reference/generated/root_numpy.array2root.html#root_numpy.array2root

Comment: Thats the website where I found the commands on. It doesnt really help with troubleshooting though. Edit: What exactly does dtypes.names and dtypes.fields mean?  I dont understand the use of the second period.

Comment: In the examples, the arrays have "column names", that is the `dtype=...` option. Does your array `sig` have those "column names"? If not, they apparently cannot be converted to ROOT data.

Comment: Interesting. Ill try that out and let you know what happens. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! It took a while to figure out how to make a list of tuples, but once I figured it out, I have my files. Thank you so much!